# Posting with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I do this in jquery?
I would like to post data, process, and then retrieve the page that is generated by that data.

All I can find are seperate just post. or just retrieve data.

Comment: Do you an ajax request or just force a normal form submission?

Comment: What would happen is almost like a dynamic search. where the user would submit the search form and the result will dynamically show below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might as well try this example:

Client Side:

```
Search: <input type="text" id="criteria" />
<button id="searchButton">Go</button>
<div id="results">
</div>

<script>
    var q = $('#criteria').val();    
    $.post('search.php',{'query':q},function(result){
        $('#results').html(result);
    });
</script>
```

Server Side(search.php):

```
<?php        
    $q = $_ POST['query'];
    //do some query on db
    //display the results
    //do some print
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

jQuery has the [`jQuery.post` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post) to do that:

```
jQuery.post(
    'http://example.com/…',
    {/* post data of key-value pairs */},
    function(data, textStatus) {
        /* callback function to process the response */
    }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

To post the data you use `$.post`. The return value would be in the first parameter of the calback function.

For example:

```
$.post('urlToPostTo', null, function(data){
   alert(data);
}
```

This will show the returned data from the server in an alert box.